# Link to page with custom posts?

Tags: wordpress

I've created this theme with some custom post types called projects and events.

I now want to link to a "archive page" all the posts with that post type. How is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try wp_query class you can cusomize it with the post type. 
read more here http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_.26_Status_Parameters

then you may do so with a condition to change the code in achhive page from:

```
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
```

to:

```
$cat_posts = new WP_Query($query_string."post_type=projects");
if ($cat_posts->have_posts()) : while($cat_posts->have_posts()) : 
    $cat_posts->the_post();
```